# how to display comma separated values in different labels after splitting them in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net

i have comma separated values like English,Science in lblsubject.text which i am separating using the code below.
   The code given below displays Science in both the Label1 as well as Label2 as it gets overridden...but I want to display English in one label and science in another label. 
how to do it...pls help..!

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(lblsubject.Text, ",");

foreach (string line in lines)
 {
   Label1.Text = line;
   Label2.Text = line;          
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You will get two elements in the array, why are you using the foreach loop. you can do

```
Label1.Text = lines[0];
Label2.Text = lines[1];
```

Comment: @Prajakta, you are welcome, since its your first day on StackOverFlow please accept any answer you think is correct see [How accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add labels dynamically, if you don't know how many there will be.  (Note also, Regex.Split is overkill for this, you could just use the String.Split extension method.)

```
string[] lines = lblsubject.Text.Split(',');

for (int i=0 ; i<lines.Length ; i++)
{
    var newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.Text = lines[i];
    form1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
}
```

Where *form1* could be any container control that you want to add your labels to.

Another alternative could be to add HTML directly to your output.  Something like this:

```
var html = string.Join("<br/>", 
    lblsubject.Text.Split(',').Select( 
        category => string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", category) 
    )
);
panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(html));
```

(Where again, *panel1* is just a container for your output.)

**Edit, per comment**

```
DrowDownList1.Items.AddRange(
    lblsubject.Text.Split(',')
        .Select(category => new ListItem(category))
        .ToArray()
);
```

Comment: well i followed your second answer as well but actually i have to add the label's text in DropDownList control..i tried by writing DropDownList1.Items.Add(newLabel) but it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Split()` function

```
string[] lines = lblsubject.Text.Split(',');

Label1.Text = lines[0];         
Label2.Text = lines[1];
```

Comment: ya i have used this...but what if there are more subjects??

Comment: for N values use a for or foreach loop